# Send form when with mysql_fetch_array while loop CLOSED

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have got a while loop that runs through all the records of the database printing them on a table. Now i also have some checkboxes within that very loop that I want to use to submit a form when clicked. Now when I click the checkbox it will indeed submit the form thanks to a Jquery script I found, BUT whenever i submit it it submits with the ID of the first record of the table.[This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwwSL.png)

shows the table, as you see the first record has ID 34. Now every checkbox I click will send the $id 34.

This does not happen with normal submit buttons.

Is there a way I can submit with the individual userID's

```html
while ($openResInfo = mysql_fetch_array($openResQuery))
            {
                $id = $openResInfo[0];
                $complete = $openResInfo[7];
            
            ?>
                    <form id='resComplete' action='dashboard_openReserveringen_PHP.php' method='GET'>
                        <?php
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='userID' value='$id'>";
                        ?>                   
                        <input type="hidden" name="complete" value="0" >
                        <input id='complete' type='checkbox' name='complete' value='1' onchange='$("#resComplete").submit();' <?php if($complete == 1){echo "checked";}?>>
   
                    </form>
```

I'm sorry if i'm not very clear with the explanation it is quite hard to explain this situation. Thank you guys!

Comment: Show the `$('#resComplete').submit` function

Comment: you're generating MULTIPLE tags with the same `id`, which is illegal html. dom id's must be UNIQUE across the entire document.

Comment: Its a trick to send the value of empty checkboxes @MarcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your problem is that you are submiting the same form always and its because you create a form for each row but it has the same id

For you the easy way is to put each form with the id cointaining the unique value of the row and doing submit with that.

Something like this

```
while ($openResInfo = mysql_fetch_array($openResQuery))
            {
                $id = $openResInfo[0];
                $complete = $openResInfo[7];

            ?>
                    <form id='resComplete_<?php echo $id; ?>' action='dashboard_openReserveringen_PHP.php' method='GET'>
                        <?php
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='userID' value='$id'>";
                        ?>                   
                        <input type="hidden" name="complete" value="0" >
                        <input id='complete' type='checkbox' name='complete' value='1' onchange='$("#resComplete_<?php echo $id; ?>").submit();' <?php if($complete == 1){echo "checked";}?>>

                    </form>
```

Comment: But i also would suggest to create only a form , outside the loop and use a class on the check to do a submit on the same form.

Also i see you are using a hidden to get the checked value and the check has the same name...you could have problems with that.

The checkboxes recive a on value if they are checked 
Use this php code to get the value without using a hidden field ;)

`$complete = ($_POST("complete) ) == "on" ? 1: 0; `

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped!  @Caius

Comment: @WilliamBruijntjes np mate , have a nice programming ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `<form>` your creating has a static id, so ALL forms will have `id='resComplete'`. The jQuery submit function will grab the first element with `id='resComplete'` and submit it. You need to make it unique for every form and make the `onchange='$("#resComplete").submit();'` code match it.

Eg.

```
<?php
while ($openResInfo = mysql_fetch_array($openResQuery))
            {
                $id = $openResInfo[0];
                $complete = $openResInfo[7];

            ?>
                    <form id='resComplete-<?php echo $id; ?>' action='dashboard_openReserveringen_PHP.php' method='GET'>
                        <?php
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='userID' value='$id'>";
                        ?>                   
                        <input type="hidden" name="complete" value="0" >
                        <input id='complete' type='checkbox' name='complete' value='1' onchange='$("#resComplete-<?php echo $id; ?>").submit();' <?php if($complete == 1){echo "checked";}?>>

                    </form>
```

Better yet, use jQuery to find out what form it's in by chaning the onchange to something like:

```
<input id='complete' type='checkbox' name='complete' value='1' onchange='$(this).closest('form').submit();' <?php if($complete == 1){echo "checked";}?>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Both answers really helped! @Anialation